# Background color different even row

Tags: css, background-color

I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
 </div>
```

I would like that for even class="row" all childs div have a background (blue for example) and for odd class="row" all childs div have a background (red for example)

so the result would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="background:blue">something</div>
    <div style="background:blue">something</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div style="background:red">something</div>
    <div style="background:red">something</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with CSS

```css
.container > .row:nth-child(even) > div{
  background: red;
}

.container > .row:nth-child(odd) > div{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them inside of a container like so:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
  </div>
</div>

.container row:nth-child(even) div
{
background: blue
}

.container row:nth-child(odd) div
{
background: red
}
```

Comment: This is not working, if you removed `style="background:blue"` from div, all div's will have the same background, in your case red.